# Regularity of locally finite Borel measure

Tags: measure-theory, regularity, borel-sets

Do you know any proof that locally finite Borel measure on metric space is regular ? I found many proofs only for finite Borel measure, but it's not satisfies me. Or maybe do you know any books or websites where I can find that proof ?

Author of the article "Sobolev spaces on metric-measure spaces" considers that kind of problem on the 69 page, but he assumes "without lose of generality" that measure of whole space is finite, but I can't understand that "without lose"...

Comment: It's not even true that every finite Borel measure on a metric space is regular (w.r.t. compact subsets), at least if we are using the axiom of choice. Any unmeasurable subset $X \subseteq [0,1]$ admits a non-regular Borel probability measure, and is a separable metric space with its subspace topology.

Comment: The statement you are looking for is probably that every locally finite Borel measure on a *separable complete* metric space $X$ is regular. On such a space, every open cover has a countable subcover (this is easy to prove directly and is called being Lindelöf) so every locally finite measure is $\sigma$-finite. For every $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$, there is a probability measure $\nu$ with the same null sets, so $\mu$ is regular iff $\nu$ is. This then follows from Ulam's theorem that finite measures on Polish spaces are regular.

Comment: The answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22174/regular-borel-measures-on-metric-spaces) may also be useful. Note also that in the book you've cited (which I'm assuming is [this one](https://homepages.uc.edu/~shanmun/book.pdf)), a "metric-measure space" is assumed to be separable. Also, the proposition on page 69 deals with inner regularity with respect to *closed* sets.

Comment: @Michael What don't you understand about Lemmas 3.3.27 and 3.3.28? Or is it how to get from there to having a probability measure?

Comment: My problem has started, when I've seen article [link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.04233.pdf). Author defines metric measure space in Definition 2.1 and used by him metric space doesn't have to be separable. In fact, I wonder whether we could approximate every Borel set by closed set from down, using author's definition of metric measure space. Maybe regularity is too general, but it would be enough, so I tried to prove it. @GabeConant Sorry, I missed that detail (separability) in the article I've citied before, so it seems to be useless...

Comment: If you mean inner regularity with respect to closed sets, then every finite measure on a metric space is regular -- I assumed you meant with respect to compact sets. I don't know what happens for (non-finite) locally finite measures in the general case where the metric space isn't separable, though.