# Meagre sets with measure zero

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

It is well known that [meagre sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set) (in topology theory) and sets of measure zero (in measure theory) are generally not the same things ([O], see also [a related question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43478/is-there-a-measure-zero-set-which-isnt-meagre)). A set that is small in one sense may be large in the other sense. But surely, from the names suggested, should the opposite be true at least for some common [regular measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure)? In particular, let $X$ be a locally convex metrizable space, I would like to know

(i) If $A$ is a set of the first category of $X$, does there exist a (probability) regular measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that $\mu(A) = 0$?

(ii) Would the [Gaussian measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_measure#Gaussian_measures_on_infinite-dimensional_spaces) on $X$ be a positive answer for (i)?

**Reference:**
[O] *Oxtoby, J. C.*, Measure and category. A survey of the analogies between topological and measure spaces, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 2. New York-Heidelberg-Berlin: Springer- Verlag. VIII, 95 p. (1971). [ZBL0217.09201](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0217.09201).

Comment: (i) say, a $\delta$-measure concentrated in a point outside $A$.  (ii) if $X=\mathbb{R}$, a Gaussian measure is equivalent to Lebesgue measure and it does not always work.

Comment: @Fedor: (i) By this logic, I guess I can basically take any measure whose support lies outside $A$. (ii) Ah, right. I keep thinking about the infinite-dimensional $X$ so don't see the obvious. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: (i) sure you can, this is rather tautological. But sometimes a measure with greater supports (intersecting $A$) may also work.

Comment: Perhaps a more interesting question is: is there a Borel probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to which *every* meager set is null?

Comment: @NikWeaver: This was answered here, the answer is *no*: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342798/is-there-a-measure-on-0-1-that-is-0-on-meagre-sets-and-1-on-co-meagre-sets?rq=1

Comment: @ChristianRemling ah, nice!

Comment: (i) You did not require completeness, you could easily have $X$ first category in itself.  For example, the subspace of normed space $l^2$ consisting of sequences that are zero except for a finite number of coordinates.  A normed space is certainly locally convex and metrizable.

Comment: (ii) I think this is likely false as well.  Can we prove (or disprove) this for the classical Wiener measure on $C[0,1]$, for example?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: As noted in the post linked by Christian Remling, for every Borel probability measure on a metric space, there is a meager set of full measure.  With Wiener measure, a nice example is to take the Holder space $A = C^{0,\alpha}[0,1] \subset C[0,1]$ for $\alpha < 1/2$.  It's a standard fact that Brownian motion is a.s. $\alpha$-Holder-continuous for $\alpha < 1/2$, so $\mu(A) = 1$, but $A$ is easily seen to be $\sigma$-compact (by Arzela-Ascoli) and therefore meager.