# Prove that there is no finite Borel measure $\mu$ such that set of $\mu$-negligible sets equals the set of meager sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that $([0,1],B([0,1]),\mu)$ is a measure space, here $B([0,1])$ is the set of all Borel sets on $[0,1]$, let $N_{\mu}$ be the set of all subsets $S$ of $[0,1]$ such that $S$ is $\mu$-negligible, let $M$ be the set of all meager sets contained in $[0,1]$. I want to show that there is no finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that $N_{\mu}=M$, how to show this? Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Come to think of it, it is actually a duplicate of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342798/129074), I believe.

Comment: The question has already been answered satisfactorily, but it's worth pointing out that the existence of a Borel measure on $X$ such that meager sets have measure zero imposes topological restrictions on $X$ which are not satisfied by the usual topology on the real line (but are, e.g., by the density topology). Chapter 22 of Oxtoby's book *Measure and Category* has more on this. I'll try to post an excerpt as an answer later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a measure on $[0,1]$ that is 0 on meagre sets and 1 on co-meagre sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/342798/is-there-a-measure-on-0-1-that-is-0-on-meagre-sets-and-1-on-co-meagre-sets)

Answer (score 5):

It follows easily from the following result.

> **Lemma.**
> For any finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ (possibly $\mu=0$) and $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $1/3<a<1/2<b<2/3$ such that $[0,a]\cup[b,1]$ has measure at least $(1-\varepsilon)\mu([0,1])$.

Indeed, you can then iterate the argument with $\varepsilon$ going to zero fast enough that the closed sets you construct always have measure at least 1/2 and the diameters of the connected components go to zero. The intersection of those is a closed set of empty interior and positive measure.

To prove the lemma, notice that there are finitely many atoms of mass at least $\varepsilon/2$, then choose $a=x-\delta$, $b=x+\delta$ for $x$ outside of this finite set and $\delta>0$ small enough.

Answer (score 3):

The question has already been answered satisfactorily, but let me give a reference to a more general statement.  If $X$ is a topological space with a finite measure $\mu$ defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of sets having the property of Baire, and if $\mu(E)=0$ iff $E$ is meager, then $(X,\mu)$ is said to be a **category measure space**.  So your question, after completing the measure to the $\sigma$-algebra of sets having the property of Baire, is whether $[0,1]$ admits a measure $\mu$ such that the pair is a category measure space (a category measure for short).

The answer is negative by virtue of theorem 22.2 in John Oxtoby's book *Measure and Category* (2d ed. 1980, Springer GTM **2**): if $X$ is a regular Baire space [recall that this means that every comeager space is dense, which is the case of $[0,1]$] which admits a category measure as defined in the previous paragraph, then every meager set is nowhere dense.  Clearly this is not the case if $[0,1]$ (as the set of rationals is meager but dense).

On the other hand, if we replace the usual topology on $[0,1]$ by the [density topology](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Density_topology), then meager sets are exactly Lebesgue null sets, so the Lebesgue measure becomes a category measure.

Comment: I just want to mention that starting from any probability space $(X,\mu)$ there is a canonical way to generate an associated category measure space $(\hat X, \hat \mu)$, by taking $\hat X$ to be the Gelfand dual of $L^\infty(X,\mu)$ (viewed as a $C^*$-algebra), and defining $\hat \mu$ via the Riesz representation theorem; alternatively, one can apply the Loomis-Sikorski theorem to the measure algebra of $X$.  See Section 7 and Remark 9.1 of this paper of myself and Asgar Jamneshan: https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.00681 .  We call $(\hat X,\hat \mu)$ the canonical model of $(X,\mu)$.